# R language, dnorm function

Tags: r, statistics

Why it returns vector value 0.24197072 0.05399097? I expect one value which means probability(1,2)???

```
mu=c(0,0)
sigma=c(1,1)

print(dnorm(c(1,2), mu, sigma))
```

Comment: it is bivariate distribution, that's why i pass 2 mu and sigma

Comment: For bivariate normal see package `mvtnorm`, function `dmvnorm`. (There are other packages that include the multivariate normal distribution.)

Comment: you are getting two values because it is returning the density for both `1` and `2` from the same distribution, you can also simplify your code to this `dnorm(1:2,0,1)`